# How to set up Drupal Plugin Manager on MAMP in a secure way?

Tags: security, ftp, drupal, mamp

I use MAMP PRO as global webserver. First of all, is it a good idea? Secondly, my objective is to run a Drupal website with as easy management as possible. Now I want to use [Plugin Manager](http://drupal.org/project/plugin_manager) module to install additional modules and themes for my website. It wants to use ftp for that, and I know that if I open access to FTP port then IT-department guys will come to me and ask to shut it down. So I wonder if there is a way to allow Plugin Manager to install modules, having the port 21 closed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MAMP is not secure as a global webserver.  You can do things to make it more secure, but in general, it is not out of the box.  It is designed to provide a development environment for web developers.

Not knowing much about Plugin Manager, I downloaded it and I see there's an ssh.backend.inc so it may be possible to use ssh rather than ftp.